# Undo or remove tag edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just edited a tag excerpt by adding links to the libraries referenced in the tag [jsnetworkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsnetworkx). Unfortunately, I had forgotten that tag excerpts are plain text, and now that I've realized this would like to remove or undo my suggested edit. Is this possible, and if so, how can I remove this suggested edit? Presumably anyone who reviews my suggested edit will reject it, but I thought I could at least save folks the trouble.

Comment: I've "improved" the edit you submitted by removing the attempted links, and then marked your attempted edit as helpful 'cause your heart was in the right place.  This has [removed it from the queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5185535).  I find it utterly depressing that people actually attempted to approve a wiki excerpt edit that would be *completely broken*.

Comment: @Charles I am shocked as well. Perhaps they forgot excerpts are plain text, too? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't find it very shocking that other reviewers approved the suggested edit. Not everyone interacts with tags enough to know that markdown isn't supported in excerpts (unlike every other aspect of the site). The excerpt editor ought to detect and reject attempts to insert markdown.

Comment: I have just made a similar mistake. I edited the tag wiki for 'snap-framework' http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/70126 when I attempted to edit the wiki for 'snap' http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/8183 How can I remove the suggested edit from the queue?

Comment: To fix this, I have added another edit to the queue to restore the text of 'snap-framework' http://stackoverflow.com/tags/snap-framework/info (I also tweaked the markdown slightly.)